# Iterate over dict got from another dict

Tags: ansible

This is my Ansible task:

```yaml
- name: Create all daemon supervisor files
  ansible.builtin.template:
    src: supervisor_daemon_template.j2
    dest: /tmp/asd/{{item.brand}}_{{ item.daemon_name }}.conf
  
  # this works
  loop: "{{ app_daemons.app1 }}" 

  # But I want something like that:
  # loop: "{{ lookup('ansible.builtin.vars', app_daemons, inventory_hostname ) }}" 
  
  vars:
    app_daemons:
      app1:
        - { daemon_name: 'receiver', brand: 'nokia' }
        - { daemon_name: 'parser', brand: 'nokia' }
      app2:
        - { daemon_name: 'receiver', brand: 'samsung' }
        - { daemon_name: 'parser', brand: 'samsung' }
```

I want to create the files accordingly to the current `{{ inventory_hostname }}` that can be either `app1` or `app2`.

How can I do this?

Comment: `loop: "{{ app_daemons[inventory_hostname] }}"`. The lookup if when you have a variable to access at top level, here you have a dictionary, so you can access its property with brackets.